# IDEA prompts“The ‘android’command is deprecated.”when creating compiled file on uiautomator project

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

pls help me，thanks~
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJgpg.png)
C:\Users\kola\IdeaProjects\UiautomatorCase>android create uitest-project -n UiautomatorCase -t 1 -p .

---

The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

Answer (score 0):

pls ignore above contents，when creating compiled files，IDEA prompts：The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

Comment: Use Android Studio

Comment: thx for your reply,i have found the reason，because my sdk version is too new:)